# How git and GitHub work with push and pull for syncing data

Tags: android, mysql, git, sqlite, synchronization

I am working on a project that needs to sync my server side MySQL to my App SQLite and vice versa. The project will be having both portal and App side implementation.

**PUSH**

I have successfully implemented the app side where a user can insert a new data into the SQLite Database with sync status 'N' if no internet connection is available. If internet connection changes (Internet connection switched ON), App sends its data from SQLite with sync status 'N' to the server for new insert into the MySQL database. After inserting that data successfully, server sends its response to the app as "success", so that App can update the status of the data (with sync status 'N') to new status 'Y'.

If internet connection available, both server and app side databases are inserted with sync status 'Y'.

The problem is with the reverse process...

**UPDATE**

When a user wants to insert new data from the portal side, at first the server side database will be inserted with the new data with sync status 'N'. Now when app wants to sync (can be done with the same request for sync from app (push) as above or a new request for sync (update)), the server will be sending the data of which the sync status are 'N'. After successfully fetching the response of the server, app will insert the new data to its SQLite database with sync status 'Y'...

The problem is how the server can know if the app side *successfully* inserted the data into SQLite so that server can update the data sync status from 'N' to 'Y'? Is there any way to give response to the server (the reverse process!) from the app?

- Am I doing anything wrong?
- Will my concept work or is there any other way to implement this sync concept?
- How Git and GitHub is pushing data and updating its database?

PS: I have already searched for the similar queries and that does not satisfy me. I do not want to use any framework. In our project full customisation support would be necessary.

Comment: This has nothing to do with git and github. With git/github, you're manually telling it to push/pull. But for your app's case, you want to sync when internet connection is available. Both cases are different

Comment: Yes, I understand the trigger time and method is different. But otherwise they are also using same sync concept! How they keep track of all the changes and new updates, that is my question?

Comment: When users inserts new data in portal (server), you send a push notification to the phone. You'll get the notification when there is internet connectivity, therefore you won't have to check for internet. Then update the phone's database and if the transaction is successful, send an ack request to the server.

Comment: push notification is not always received as far as I have experienced. Though sending a ack request to the server is a good idea.

Comment: *"otherwise they are also using same sync concept!"*  No, they really aren't.  Git doesn't actually keep track of changes.  It keeps track of entire files.  Using these, it can *show* you the differences between two versions of a file, but that does not mean it is actually tracking diffs.

Comment: can you please elaborate how git works with tracking files?